# What is the best way to persist login and password SQL Server when used from ASP.NET app that uses SMO?

Tags: asp.net, smo

I am creating a simple web management studio using SMO. Is it secure enough to persist/store user information (login and password for database) using ASP.NET mechanism (e.g. formsauthentication, cookies, etc.).

What will be the best practice to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is very secure but you must consider this:

- User requireSSL = true
- cookieless = false
- enableCrossAppRedirects=false
- httpOnlyCookies="true"

also for the role manager do not cache the roles in cookie

```
<roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="false">
```

non "out of the box" system is 100% what you looking for, and you maybe need to think what other extra messure you need to take for make it even more secure.

Also you can open the database and see what informtions is stored on it, to see if are meet your requirements. The password is not saved, but the salt of it, so you can not read it, and it save is the email/name of your user.

Some extra reference

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650037.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/24/ASP.NET-2.0-Membership_2C00_-Roles_2C00_-Forms-Authentication_2C00_-and-Security-Resources-.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972969.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163807.aspx

Comment: thanks for your answer, however I want to store the login and password for database, and how can I persist this if my client changes the password for his login to db?

Comment: @Arief there is all ready a module that change the password. But even if you do not use it, there is examples that you do that... just google it and you find a lot of.